# Error: Expression must have (Pointer-to-) function type

Tags: c++, function, pointers, types

I am writing a function that spits out what are called Stirling numbers. The code that I've written is as follows:

```
int SecondStirling(const int& k, const int&n){
    if(k<0||n<0) return 0;
    if(k==0 && n>0) return 0;
    if(k>0 && n==0) return 0;
    if(k>n) return 0;
    if(k==n) return 1;
    else return k(SecondStirling(k,n-1))+SecondStirling(k-1,n-1);
}
```

However, I am getting an error on the last line: Error: Expression must have (Pointer-to-) function type, the error specifically referring to k. What gives?

Comment: What does `k(SecondStirling(k,n-1))` mean?

Comment: run the function with inputs (k,n-1), and multiply the result by k.

Comment: You mean `k * SecondStirling(k,n-1)`?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike in math, the multiplication operator `*` can't be omitted. Change

```
k(SecondStirling(k,n-1))
```

to

```
k * (SecondStirling(k,n-1))
```

Answer (score 3):

By writing

```
k(SecondStirling(k,n-1))
```

You are trying to call a function named "k", or pointed by "k", accepting a single parameter of type int (which is returned by SecondStirling). 
However "k" is an int variable, hence the error.
The correct syntax, as already pointed out, is

```
k * (SecondStirling(k,n-1))
```